# Get special value from SimpleXMLElement Object

Tags: php, xml

This is my XML content

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [Item] => Array
        (
            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [Job.P_Id] => 10005
                    [Job.P_Owner] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [User] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [User.P_Id] => 1
                                )

                        )

                    [Job.P_Client] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [Client] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [Client.P_Id] => 10003
                                )

                        )

                    [Job.P_PhaseDate] => 2018/08/01 09:04:00
                    [Job.P_Position] => Sample 2

                )

        )

)
```

Now I want to get some elements like `Job.P_Id`, `User.P_Id` but I can't get that by the normal way like:

```
$xml->Item[0]->Job.P_Id
```

or

```
$xml->Item[0]["Job.P_Id"]
```

So, is there any easily way to get what I want?

Comment: $xml->Item[0]->{'Job.P_Id'}

Comment: And yes - it's strange to name nodes with dot.

Comment: It's a third-party app that I want to get information from :))